# Using Kafkalytic in IntelliJ gives timeout error

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, apache-kafka

I am trying to use the **KafkaLytic** plug-in [KafkaLytic](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11946-kafkalytic/versions)  and   [source here](https://github.com/ermadan/kafkalytic) in IntelliJ to connect to Kafka.  When I add broker list and do Test Connection, it is successful.  But then when I add the other properties, and try to get the list of Consumers or Topics, I get a pop-up error about timeout.

What could I be missing?

These are the properties I have added

```
ssl.truststore.location=C:/dev/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.keystore.location=C:/dev/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="username" \
    password="password";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

Comment: @danilaermakov - Do you have any suggestion?